# Would spells that modify your attack bonus, such as Bless also apply to Spiritual Weapon or Bigby's hand?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, attack-roll

Would a spell or ability that affects a characters attack roll bonus be applied to spells that also make 'melee' attacks such as Spiritual Weapon or Bigby's Hand?

As per the [Bless](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bless) spell:

> You bless up to three creatures of your choice within range. Whenever a target makes an attack roll or a saving throw before the spell ends, the target can roll a d4 and add the number rolled to the attack roll or saving throw.

So as per Bless, you are targeting the creature, the creature then casts a spell that creates a magical object that also has the ability to make an attack roll. Would Bless transfer to the spell object?

I see an argument of Yes as since you are targeting the **creature** and the **creature** is the one summoning the spectral weapon as per Spiritual Weapon or Translucent Hand, which they then control, Bless should still apply.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the spell. For the two spells you have as examples, we have yes and maybe.

Spiritual weapon:

> you can make a melee spell attack

Certainly yes, the caster is making an attack

Bigby's Hand:

> Make a melee spell attack for the hand using your game statistics.

This is more arguable. The hand is attacking with the caster's statistics. A DM will have to decide whether Bless is part of that.

Comment: For reference, these are the two spells of interest as they are commonly used by the Sorcerer and Wizard in my group.

Comment: It isn’t clear to me that Bigby’s works here. “For the hand” seems to indicate that the hand is attacking, not the caster, compared to spiritual weapon which explicitly says the caster is attacking.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov That's a valid reading

Comment: @Caleth Changed my down to an up, I agree that bigby could go either way.

Comment: fwiw i would not allow it for Bigby's Hand, it's clear enough to me that the hand attacks as a separate entity

Comment: @AnnaAG: Bigby's Hand isn't a creature, so that would make it impossible for a cleric to help it hit, if blessing the caster doesn't work, and they can't bless the hand directly.  That's not a very strong argument, though; perhaps it's intended that Bigby's Hand can't have its attack roll boosted with Bless, or bardic inspiration or similarly worded features.